# Magento in Linux not sending emails

Tags: php, magento, smtp

I have installed magento 1.8.1.0 in Linux. I installed SMTP Pro Email extension by Aschroder. I have configured all the settings and email is sent from Windows. But when I try the same thing in Linux email procesing is not working.

I read in some article that changing locale to US solves the issue. I tried that too but nothing happened.

Comment: Why do you using SMTP module?, you trying to use external email service for Magento email sending?

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you [http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch21*:_Configuring_Linux_Mail_Servers#.U5nDLPmSy1A](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch21_%3a_Configuring_Linux_Mail_Servers#.U5nDLPmSy1A)

Answer (score 0):

Oky i cant help you with that extension, but do this update to use ANY external SMTP service for Magento email sending:

**Create duplicate of function from Magento Core:**

Create copy of file

from:

`/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`

to

`/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php` (if folders do not exist create them)

**Change /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php file at about row 325 change function from:**

```
/**
 * Send mail to recipient
 *
 * @param   array|string       $email        E-mail(s)
 * @param   array|string|null  $name         receiver name(s)
 * @param   array              $variables    template variables
 * @return  boolean
 **/
public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
{
    if (!$this->isValidForSend()) {
        Mage::logException(new Exception('This letter cannot be sent.')); // translation is intentionally omitted
        return false;
    }
```

to:

```
/**
     * Send mail to recipient
     *
     * @param   array|string       $email        E-mail(s)
     * @param   array|string|null  $name         receiver name(s)
     * @param   array              $variables    template variables
     * @return  boolean
     **/
    public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
    {
        if (!$this->isValidForSend()) {
            Mage::logException(new Exception('This letter cannot be sent.')); // translation is intentionally omitted
            return false;
        }
/* hack */
       $config = array(
               'ssl' => 'tls', //optional
               'port' => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port'), //optional - default 25
               'auth' => 'login',
               'username' => 'sender_email_account@domain.somethig',
               'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host'),
               'password' => 'password'
           );

       $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp(Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host'), $config);
/**/
```

Set configuration params of your email account provider (the same as for outlook or etc...)

Thats all, your email should work